# how to make a function call itself recursively in python based on response

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Team: I am a beginnner and have put up a code that talks to pagerduty API and then it fethces oncall info for a team. response is loaded in a json and then am fetching the values I need and saving them into dictionary.

my concern is my code works perfectly as per my understanding but am trying to handle scale situations and also better approach in logic that i have used.

1 - performance at scale: ex: if returned response from api is huge then is my looping efficient resource and time wise? ex: what will happen if i set limit=10000

2 - is there a better approach?

reference https://pagerduty.github.io/pdpyras/

3 - lastly, am trying to figure out how to call the same function recursively until the team is found in record `i['name'] == testteamnm` because I don't want to pull all records unnecessarily and pull only if needed. there are like 1K teams but in recursive call I have to specify increment offset of 10 every time.

```
from pdpyras import APISession
session = APISession(PD_API_KEY, default_from="team@test.com")


       total = 1 #true or false
        limit = 10
        offset = limit + 1
        teams = session.get('/teams?limit={0}&total={1}'.format(limit,total))
        testteamnm = "Test Team"
        to_dict = dict()
        if teams.ok:
            print(teams.json())
            tj = teams.json()['teams']

            for i in tj:
                if i['name'] == testteamnm:
                    to_dict.update({i['id']:i['name']})
                    break
            else:
                print("In the limit {} fetched from PD API, test team was not found. call this functtion recursively until team is found. Hence set offset to {} and fetch further".format(limit,offset))   

if __name__== "__main__":
    o = TEAMPDClass()
    o.pagerduty_oncall()
```

sample output with limit

```
{'teams': [{'id': 'PCBBSDD', 'name': '[obsolete] Old Survey API', 'description': None, 'type': 'team', 'summary': '[obsolete] GX Old Survey API', 'self': 'https://api.pagerduty.com/teams/PCZBSDD', 'html_url': 'https://team.pagerduty.com/teams/PCLBSDD', 'default_role': 'manager', 'parent': None}, {'id': 'PISLGYQ', 'name': 'Mobile Client', 'description': None, 'type': 'team', 'summary': 'Mobile Client', 'self': 'https://api.pagerduty.com/teams/PISGSYQ', 'html_url': 'https://team.pagerduty.com/teams/PIGCSYQ', 'default_role': 'manager', 'parent': None}, {'id': 'PAVY84Y', 'name': 'Shield Client', 'description': None, 'type': 'team', 'summary': 'Android Shield Client', 'self': 'https://api.pagerduty.com/teams/PAXY84Y', 'html_url': 'https://team.pagerduty.com/teams/PAGT84Y', 'default_role': 'manager', 'parent': None}], 'limit': 3, 'offset': 0, 'total': 1001, 'more': True}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to use recursion here. Just use a loop.

Comment: If the API supports supports an offset/size strategy then you could consider multithreading (or multiprocessing if the data processing is CPU intensive) rather than calling the API with a single, high, limit. EDIT: A quick look at the API documentation suggests that you can pass an offset (classic pagination)

Comment: the response tells you if there are more results. your function will check this response field, if there are no more, then response is the last one. otherwise there are more so your function will recur and fetch the next batch.

Comment: @OldBill Good input for MT MP sure will incorporate but I will still need to call func recurse because max records I can pull is 100 at a time. So was looking in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

I leveraged loop as suggested in first comment of my question. Posting answer here but please comment if anyone has concerns. it works for me.

```
        if teams.ok:
        tj = teams.json()
            tjd = tj['teams']
            for i in tjd:
                if i['name'] == testteamnm:
                    testteamid = i['id']
                    print("\nFetched",i['name'], "id: {0}".format(testteamid))
                    break
                else:
                    print("Check team in next set of team records...")
            else:
                if tj['offset'] <= tj['total'] or tj['more'] == True:
                    offset = tj['offset'] + limit #0(0-9), 10(10-19), 20(20-29)..etc
                    print("Recursively search all team records with limit {} fetched from PD API at a time. Setting offset to {} from previous index".format(limit,offset))
                    self.pagerduty_oncall(offset)
                else:
                    print("fetched all records..ending loop")
        else:
            print("Call to PagerDuty API end point failed...")
```